# How to make user defined rectangular array and itirate over it

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

So, I have this school asignement and I just can't get it right.
I'm supposed to make a rectangular array, size defined by the user then I have to print all the values within the array.
It ought to look like this:

[image: expected output]

This is my code so far ([on github](https://github.com/higashi04/arraymethdosforskool/blob/main/Program.cs)):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Ingrese un número entero: ");
   int userValue = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //el número ingresado por el usuario es guardado en una variable
   if (userValue <= 10 && userValue > 0) //valida que el número ingresado sea igual o menor a 10 y mayor que 0
   {
        int[,] rectArray = new int[userValue,userValue]; //la variable que registra el número dado por el usuario es usada para definir el tamaño del arreglo
        Console.WriteLine("Los valores del arreglo son:");
        for (int file = 0; file < rectArray.GetLength(0); file++)
        {   
            if (file > 0) {Console.WriteLine(" " + file);}; //Se utiliza un condicional para evitar que se imprima la primer línea con valor de 0
            for (int column = 0; column < rectArray.GetLength(1); column++)
            {
                int colValue = column + file + 1;
                Console.Write(" " + colValue );
            };
        };
        Console.ReadKey();
   } 
    else
   {
       Console.WriteLine("El valor necesita ser igual o menor a 10.");
       Console.ReadKey();
   };
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] and add the code AS TEXT in the question. [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Johnny, the image is the terminal output. It should print 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 etc for each file and column.

Comment: Peter, when I run the code my output is 01234561 12345671 etc for each file and column. It ought to be 1234567 then 2345678 and so on for each file and column

Comment: First advice, Fill your array, then print the array out. it will be much simpler.. second, you are already tracking the rows in your first loop. so just remove  `if (file > 0) {Console.WriteLine(" " + file);}; ` and add console.writeline() after second loop (after line 22) and lastly your second loop should start with 1. so you dont need `column + file + 1`, instead column + file is enough.

Comment: Side note for bonus points ;) If you use `int.TryParse` instead of `int.Parse` you can prevent unhandled exceptions if the user does something unwanted such as enter text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advice to separate the population logic from printing.

The population logic is almost good. You just don't need the `if` statement:

```
int[,] rectArray = new int[userValue, userValue]; 
for (int row = 0; row < userValue; row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < userValue; column++)
    {
        rectArray[row, column] = column + row + 1;
    }
}
```

The printing is almost the same but instead of assigning values to each element of the array, you need to retrieve them:

```
for (int row = 0; row < rectArray.GetLength(0); row++)
{ 
    for (int column = 0; column < rectArray.GetLength(1); column++)
    {
        Console.Write(" " + rectArray[row, column]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: The credit goes to @Behzad. We have ended up with the same solution but he was quicker than me.